# Why am I getting two answers from the same question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, power

[image: Problem from an Indian entrance test]

In this problem, if I use the formula for power as $\frac{F\cdot s}{t}$, then the answer is 37.5 W. But if I use the formula $F\cdot v$, then the answer is 75 W.

How is it possible that the man has two different powers?
Which is the correct answer and why?

Comment: Can you show your work for the two methods?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help) in this site so that others can lookup later even if the image gets deleted in the host website.

Comment: $F\cdot v$ is true for a constant force moving an object at constant velocity, this is not true in your case.

Comment: @Triatticus That is incorrect. $F\cdot v$ is valid for all cases, as it gives the instantaneous power being supplied. You don't need constant forces or constant velocities to use this equation

Comment: Instantaneous power is when you assume the changes are so small as to be approximately constant, it is only true when they are constant. It doesn't mean you can't use it but you'd need to apply calculus to do so

Comment: @Triatticus Right. The question is not very clear on whether they are asking about average power or instantaneous power. It is pretty unclear

Comment: The question is from an integer type entrance exam. So the answer according to them is 75W. But the question is clear as it asks the power developed "at" the end of 3 seconds, hence instantaneous power has to be calculated.

Comment: I got it. The question asks for instantaneous power. And the formula for instantaneous power is F.v as derived by @user221619 in his answer. So the correct answer should indeed be 75W.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you are not making a confusion bettween mean power and instantaneous power.

At the beginning, the speed is 0 and so the power is 0. And with time, the power increase. 
With your hypothesis, $v=Ft/m$ and so $P={{F}^{2}}t/m$

The work is $W(t)=\int\limits_{0}^{t}{Pdt}=P=\frac{1}{2}{{F}^{2}}t/m$ and the mean power $\left\langle P \right\rangle =\frac{W(t)}{t}=\int\limits_{0}^{t}{Pdt}=\frac{1}{2}{{F}^{2}}t/m=\frac{1}{2}P(t)$
That is why you find a factor $1/2$

Comment: I didn't understand what you did there but I got the idea. My concepts are not clear on mean and instantaneous powers.

Comment: Maybe the difference betweem mean velocity and instantaneous would be more familiar to you. The velocity of the boat increase linearly with time. It will be maximal at the end. To compute the mean velocity, you have to compute the distance (integral of the speed) and divide by the total time. Clearly, the mean velocity will be less that the maximal velocity.

Answer (score 0):

P=w/t=(F*s)/t this is average power
w=F•s
diffrentiating both side wrt time

> dw/dt=d(F•s)/dt .
>   when force is constant
>
> dw/dt=F•ds/dt=F•v.
>   now dw/dt is rate of doing work then by  defination it is power
>
> p=F•v  .
>   this gives instantenous poweras ds/dt gives velocity of that instant. your question asks for average power.so 37.5watts is correct

Comment: I think the question asks for instantaneous power. Read it again.

Comment: no because it says at end of third second from beginning of motiom